# Android Layout Templating

Tags: android, android-layout, templates, android-xml

I'm looking to a simple way to do layout templating in android.
I already check include and merge techniques without success.
(I think that it's possible creating custom Layouts and defining by code this behavior, but i wondered if that could be done by xml)

I want to define something like this:

```
 [globalLayout]
 <linearLayout params=xxx>
    <linearLayout params=yyy>
        <?yied ?>
    </linearLayout>
 </linearLayout>


 [customView1]
 <Linearlayout>
   <ImageView />
   <Button/>
 </LinearLayout>


 [customView2]
 <Linearlayout>
   <Button/>
   <Button/>
   <Button/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

### (these 3 xml should be reusable)

```
 [HomeLayout]
 <?include globalLayout >
    <?include customView1 />
 </include>


 [ParamsLayout]
 <?include globalLayout >
    <?include customView2 />
 </include>
```

---

The thing is that i want to have a reusable layout, if a perform a small change, it will affect all dependent views.  somethink linked to "partial views or templating" in other languages.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps i'm doing this wrong, but in my globalLayout I've defined a background picture, a padding and setted some global params. I'm trying to avoid stupid copy paste of this code in all my views.

Comment: While waiting for an xml solution of my problem, I've resolved my problem programatically with something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444421/custom-layout-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this before by using view stub.
You can inflate any view you like inside that view.

```
<GlobalLayout>
 <ViewStub>
<GlobalLayout>
```

Comment: How did you defined "GlobalLayout"?

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutInflater to do something like this:

On the Activity's onCreate:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new TemplateInflater(this).apply(R.layout.products)
              .onViewGroup(R.id.replace_here).ofTemplate(R.layout.template));
```

An implementation snippet:

```
public View ofTemplate(int templateId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View root = inflater.inflate(templateId, null);

    View content = inflater.inflate(contentId, null);
    ((ViewGroup)root.findViewById(viewGroupId)).addView(content);

    return root;
}
```

An example of a working code is in my git: https://github.com/erichegt/AndroidTemplating

I think this code will solve your problem, but you should use Fragments instead. You can have one Activity associated with a template and a Fragment to inflate it.

Answer (score 0):

[ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) is pretty straightforward and can cover basic layout templating needs.

It serves as a placeholder for some other layout which you can specify and inflate at runtime and then:

> The inflated View is added to the ViewStub's parent with the ViewStub's layout parameters.

Here is example from one of my projects. In my layout template I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ... >

    ...

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_1_stub"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/split_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/primary_left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/primary_right_guideline">
    </ViewStub>

    ....

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

... then, when I inflate it I am setting actual button layout that I need and inflate stub:

```
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_template, null);
    ViewStub button1Stub = contentView.findViewById(R.id.button_1_stub);
    button1Stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.work_button);
    button1Stub.inflate();
```

... which inserts layout from `R.layout.work_button` instead of stub, imposing layout constraints I defined on the `R.id.button_1_stub`.