# Custom Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone know how to implement custom layouts in android?

I have CustomLayout class.

```
CustomLayout extends LinearLayout
```

with constructors `public CustomLayout(Context context)` and `public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

I also have a xml layout (example.xml)

```
<com.myproject.layout.CustomLayout 
    android:id="@+id/cl_main"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="inside button" />

</com.myproject.layout.CustomLayout>
```

When I set the content view in my activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.example);
```

My Global layout is inflated and is showed, but the "inner button" is not inside the layout...
Any ideas?

Comment: I think your CustomLayout is occupying whole area.  give layout_height as wrapcontent.

Comment: since the button is inside, the fill_parent isn't a problem.
I want a fullscreen layout, with views inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you must override this method.

```
public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
{
    //... 
    llContainer.addView(child, fillParentLayoutParams);
    //...
}
```

where llContainer is the layout where the views should be placed.
this method is called by the inflater to populate your view with the xml definitions.