# Please help me me in custom layout in android

Tags: android, custom-component

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity `ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.Demo}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.component.MainActivity`
```

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends FrameLayout {    
>     public MainActivity(Context context) {
>         super(context);
>         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>     }
> }
> ```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Demo.java**

```
public class Demo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    }


}
```

**activity_demo.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

  <com.example.component.MainActivity
    android:id="@+id/comp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This might help                                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444421/custom-layout-in-android

Comment: Are you sure the Custom view isn't in the `com.example.demo` package, and not `com.example.component`?

Comment: hi Raghav, yes i ma sure Custom view (MainActivity) is in com.example.component package and not in  com.example.demo

Comment: I am not able to figure out my mistake, please help

Comment: One more thing com.example.component and  com.example.demo are two different packages

Comment: post your full logcat error and update it in your question

Comment: please find my logcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413320/i-am-trying-to-create-the-custom-component-but-application-get-crashed-due-to-f

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an activity in a layout. Only views or view groups.

Comment: Despite the confusing naming it actually is a `View`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I have added the 2nd constructor but issue is still the same, Please help

Comment: In hierarchy view Frame layout shows 3 red symbol, Please let me know how to resolve that

Comment: please find my logcat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413320/i-am-trying-to-create-the-custom-component-but-application-get-crashed-due-to-f

Answer (score 0):

The inflator uses the two argument constructor when it creates an instance of your view class. You must provide

```
public MainActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Comment: I have added the 3 constructor on MainActivity  and i have getting the issue as "jjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.Demo}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.component.MainActivity "

Answer (score 0):

Since Demo is your Activity, define it in Android manifest.xml file using the package name:
com.example.demo.Demo.
And why are you adding framelayout inside frameLayout use only one , your custom framelayout.
and define the xml as:

```
<com.example.component.MainActivity
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

//hope it works